# Lodash & React, Unable to access local variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash

I'm having an issue with lodash in react. I've got the following code at the beginning of my render function. I get the value of layout from this.state & then on each layout object in the array, I set static as the inverse of the boolean property isEdit. However, I've tried everything and for some reason, I cannot access isEdit within my lodash function. It's undefined... I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

```
public render() {
   const { isEdit, size } = this.props;
   const layout = this.state.layout.slice();
   _.forEach(layout, (x) => {
     x.static = !isEdit;
   });
   .....
```

Comment: Are you sure `isEdit` is being passed as a prop

Comment: @Li357 Yeah, because it's being used elsewhere in the render function and it works fine. I also lose context, so I can't do "this.props.isEdit"

Comment: No you don't. You're using an arrow function.

Comment: @Li357 yes but for some reason I am. In Dev tools once I'm in that function this is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried logging it before you enter the forEach callback?

Comment: @Li357 I'll give that a try. Could it have something to do with my webpack & ts configs?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TS. It just doesn't make sense for it to exist in other functions but not your render function, so try logging it.

Comment: What is coming inside `layout`?

Comment: @Li357 console.log returns correct Boolean

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, all *static* property on *layout* are set to be ***true***? B'cos

`!undefined would be true`.

Also can you set **defaultProp** for your **isEdit** prop, just to be sure.